# How to update Tkinter Label Text before executing some other function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to write a small GUI program using Tkinter. What I am trying to do is to create a window with a button and an input, which works just fine. However, I want the button to run some function `func` which updates the tkinter window and once that is done run whatever comes next:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

def func():
    widgets = root.grid_slaves()
    for widget in widgets:
        if int(widget.grid_info()['row']) != 0:
            widget.destroy()
            startPrompt.configure(text="Updated Text")

    startPrompt.update_idletasks()
    # root.update_idletasks()  -- I have tried both and neither work

    # Just an example of something running, to verify that the loop executes 
    # before tkinter window gets updated
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(0.5)

font = ("Helvetica", 20)
root = tk.Tk()
startPrompt = tk.Label(root, text="Starting Prompt", font=font)
inputPrompt = tk.Label(root, text="Input Prompt", font=font)
root.textEntry = tk.Entry(root, width=50)
submitButton = tk.Button(root, text="Enter", command=func, width=20, pady=10, font=font)

startPrompt.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)
inputPrompt.grid(row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
root.textEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10)
submitButton.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

The problem that I have is that no matter what I try it doesn't work. I've tried using `after()` but the way my program is written makes it very difficult to rewrite everything such that that would work properly. I have tried using `update_idletasks()` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Does anyone know why `update_idletasks()` isn't working or am I using it wrong and is there any way I can solve my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to work for me after changing a couple of things (others were mostly just little optimizations).

1. Changed `func()` to *not* use `time.sleep()` as shown below—the `after()` universal widget method can (also) be used to do this and using it doesn't interfere with the `mainloop()` running the way calling `sleep()` would.
2. Called the universal widget method **`update()`** instead of `update_idletasks()` after destruction of the widgets—but still before the counting loop runs.

Here's some [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) describing how to use the universal widget method `after()` this way (as well as what the `update()` method does).

**FWIW:** You'll be able see what's happening better if you add something like a `root.geometry('600x400')` line following the `root = tk.Tk()` statement in the initialization section of the example code in your question (not shown here) which will prevent the window from resizing after the widgets are destroyed and the display is updated.

```
def func():
    widgets = root.grid_slaves()
    for widget in widgets:
        if widget.grid_info()['row']:  # Don't need all that int() != 0 stuff.
            widget.destroy()

    startPrompt.configure(text="Updated Text")  # Only need to call once.
    root.update()  # Update display (startPrompt.update() also works here)

    # Just an example of something running, to verify that the loop executes
    # AFTER the tkinter window has been updated.
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
#        time.sleep(0.5)  # Don't use sleep in tkiner programs.
        root.after(500)  # Pause 500 millisecs.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems to be working perfectly!

Comment: dpumpkin: Unfortunately it wasn't working quite right, but I've fixed it now I believe. Anyhow, thank you.